# CSS :before and :first-child combined

Tags: css

I'm using the following code to add separators between my menu items:

```
#navigation_center li:before {

    content: "| ";
    color: #fff;

}
```

Now I want the first item not to have a separator in front of it, so I figured out the following code:

```
#navigation_center li:before:first-child {

    content: none;

}
```

but that's not doing anything. Is it possible to combine :before and :first-child?

Comment: Quick explanation of hradac answer: `:first` is a jQuery selector (and jQuery uses Sizzle, to be complete) when CSS uses `:first-child`

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations Thanks for expanding on my answer. I'm not sure but I think the order is also important where `first-child` comes before `before`, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: @hradac You're right, there's an order. As far as I can recall `:before` and `:after` should be written last, on the right. Confirmed by CSS3 Selectors module: [Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors (...)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try

```
#navigation_center li:first-child:before {
    content: '';
}
```

**Edit**: I wanted to expand on this answer with comments made by FelipeAls. The original question used `:first` which is not a valid CSS selector. Instead, use `:first-child`. Also the order of the pseudo-selectors is important. The first child selector must come first.

I tend to think of `:before` as a kind of modifier to a selector. It does not actually select an element only the space just before the selected element.

Answer (score 17):

Although [hradac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462760/hradac)'s answer should do the trick i thought it would be best to run through some possible permutations to help newcommers.

```css
.works:first-child:before
{
    color: green;
    content: 'working ';
}
.works:not(:first-child):after
{
    color: green;
    content: ' is working';
}


.broken:before:first-child
{
    color: red;
    content: 'this will never show up';
}
.broken:after:not(:first-child)
{
    color: red;
    content: 'and this will not show up either';
}
```

```html
works:
<div>
    <div class='works'>
     something
    </div>
    <div class='works'>
     something
    </div>
    <div class='works'>
     something
    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
broken:
<div>
    <div class='broken'>
     something
    </div>
    <div class='broken'>
     something
    </div>
    <div class='broken'>
     something
    </div>
</div>
```

Let's take this apart:

- Three `div.works` are inside a div
- Three `div.broken` are also inside a div
- The first rule of CSS adds a green text "working " before. It does so by selecting the `first-child` and then selecting the empty space right before it.
- The second rule adds " is working" after each block that comes after first, by analogy it first selects each block that doesn't fall under the `first-child` definition, and then selects the empty space before them.
- The following two rules, will not find a block to attach themselves to. The `:before:first-child` attempts to select an empty space, but then tests if it is a `first-child` and it is not (since technically it's not yet in the DOM tree), the similar problem is with `:not(:first-child)`.