# Line-break symbol automatically added inside a `code` environment when a line is wrapped

Tags: html, css, display

When formatting code, line wraps sometimes need to happen (in case of long lines), but it should be explicit that a line was wrapped.

Ideally, I would like to be able to write something like

```
<code class="sourceCode">
    this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.
</code>
```

but if the code needs to be wrapped, instead of adding a horizontal scrolling bar, the following would be displayed

`this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long ↲
long line which is broken.`

or

`this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long
↳ long line which is not broken`

I.e., a "↳" or a "↲" sign (and, eventually, some space) would be added when the line needs to be broken.

I'm trying to render something like this:

[image]

with pure html / css (the capture comes from [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412316/34551), which uses tex/latex and pandoc to render this document).

This issue does not seem to be related to

- the [work-break](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp), since I am not breaking any word,
- nor to the [word-wrap](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) property, since I don't really care whenever words are broken or not.

But suppose that the `code` element gets applied a `white-space: pre;` or `pre-wrap` style.

I feel that a clever `ccs` solution should exist, without actually touching the `html`, but I can't find it.

The beggining of an example could be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
      body{width: 25em}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
   <code class="sourceCode">
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.
   </code>
</body>
</html>
```

Even if, actually, the code I'm using is produced by [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) and looks more like:

```css
code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
a.sourceLine { display: inline-block; line-height: 1.25; }
.sourceCode { overflow: visible; }
code.sourceCode { white-space: pre; position: relative; }
body{width: 25em}
```

```html
<div class="sourceCode">
  <pre class="sourceCode">
    <code class="sourceCode">
      <a class="sourceLine">this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">I can have a short line as well</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">And empty lines, as well.</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.</a>
      </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite an optimal answer as it requires some things to be lined up perfectly. Since the long line is in pre, the starting position is important, does it start right after `<pre>` or on the next line? Same as ending.. It also requires you to enter enough `\A\↳` as the pseudo content. It's a proof of concept, not an easy one step solution to your problem.

```css
pre
{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
code {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
code.sourceCode:before {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    left: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    margin-left: -1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 1em;
    top: 1em;
    content: "\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳\A↳";
}
```

```html
<div class="sourceCode">
<pre class="sourceCode">        
<code class="sourceCode">
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.</code>
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice. I know it's an old answer, but this does not seem to work for multi-line content **within the same `<pre><code>`**. (For multi-line content, the second line in such code block also gets the `:before` prefix for the first part, making it feel like it's actually part of the first line.)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is as close as I can get to a solution: using `first-line`, it is possible to target the first part of the line, and to differentiate it from the wrapped part. I tried to use `background-image` with the data uri of an image like [the arrow from wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E2%86%B2), [image] to get something closer, but did not succeeded.

```css
.sourceLine{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  text-indent: 10px;
  padding-left: -10px;
  margin-right: 1em;
  display:inline-block;
}

.sourceLine{
    background-color:lightblue;
 }
 
.sourceLine:first-line{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sourceCode">
  <pre class="sourceCode">
    <code class="sourceCode">
      <a class="sourceLine">this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">I can have a short line as well</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">And empty lines, as well.</a>
      <a class="sourceLine">this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.</a>
      </code>
  </pre>
</div>
```

As a side note, note that combining `first-line` and `before` or `after` [is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16024366/2657549) ([or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822492/2657549)).
Similar questions exist ([indicate automatic line break in white-space: pre-wrap element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34684637/2657549), [CSS show indicator that line wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48870838/2657549)), but they cover slightly different aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to CSS text-indent:

```css
.sourceCode{
 text-indent: -20px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
      body{width: 25em}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sourceCode">
this is a very long long long long long long long long long long long long long line which is broken.
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's a great start, thanks, but I was more focused on adding that symbol at the beginning, or end, of each line.